# how to load a bash alias for graphical terminal emulator

Tags: bash, alias, gnome-terminal

What I'm trying to do: Load an alias

The alias: `alias notes='cd ~/project/notes'`

My system: Ubuntu 16.04 and gnome terminal 3.18.3

In my home directory there are the following bash related files:

- `.bash_history`
- `.bash_logout`
- `.bashrc`
- `.profile`

I have written this alias in `.profile` but it is not being loaded. I also  created (and later deleted) `.bash_profile` and put it there, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `.bashrc`

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add `alias notes='cd ~/project/notes'` and save file.

Run `. ~/.bashrc` to activate the alias in an existing terminal.